# How to make questions with "what" in the middle of sentence?

Tags: wh-questions

I wrote:

> Iran is supporting Palestinians, Lebanese, Syrians,… but what makes these countries terrorists?

Should it be:

> Iran is supporting Palestinians, Lebanese, Syrians,… but what does make these countries terrorists?

Or

> Iran is supporting Palestinians, Lebanese, Syrians,… but what does it make these countries terrorists?

Sometimes I get confused when and with which "wh-words"  to use auxiliary verbs to make questions. I thought if I don't use auxiliary verbs, it would be a regular sentence. For example in:

> I don't know where he went.

The sentence after *where* is not in a question mode. So, in my examples above, I was afraid that the first sentence is not a question.

Comment: This is not complicated.  These are two sentences joined by the conjunction "but".   The second sentence starting with "what" is just a normal question, *"What makes these countries terrorists?"*

Comment: @Andrew the OP is probably wondering (although he doesn't say) why there isn't an auxiliary in the "what" question.

Comment: Is the ellipses [...] in your original text or did you choose to omit what followed for the sake of brevity, and clarity? The sentence could easily start with *But what [...] these countries terroirists?* Is this for an academic paper?

Comment: I think that es after does in the second example is a typo, isn't it?

Comment: @Mari I added the source of my confusion.

Comment: @Andrew I explained it more.

Answer (score 4):

Only the first sentence is correct English:

> Iran is supporting the Palestinians, Lebanese, Syrians... but **what makes** these countries terrorists?

The reason why only the first sentence is correct and the other two are wrong has to do with the fact that for **makes** to work (which is the third-person singular form of the verb **to make**) it needs a subject and **what** is fulfilling the role of that subject (a complete sentence requires a subject and a predicate). Actually, **what** in this case is a pronoun no different from any other English pronoun we've all come to love: *he*, *she*, *it*, *you*, *we*, *they* et cetera. The only difference is that it's a special kind of pronoun known as [**an interrogative pronoun**](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/interrogative-pronouns/) (they're used for making questions while the regular ones are not). So, saying:

> **What keeps** you up at night?

is grammatically the same thing as saying:

> **He keeps** you up at night.

The only difference as noted above is that **what** turns the sentence it's in into a question.

---

But what about the following example you might ask:

> What does this word mean?

Here, the situation is different because now **what** is no longer the subject of the sentence. **this word** has stolen the role of the subject and that entailed the necessary changes in [**grammar**](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english/asking-questions-in-english/).

Comment: I think it depends on the context. In writing, I suppose it's wrong to do a do-support in an interrogative sense. For example, it's wrong to write "X is very salty, but what does make it so popular?" On the other hand, in the everyday speech I think it's not wrong to say so. Am I right?

Comment: I think you're right. It's called **the emphatic do**. For example: **What did happen?**. You would say that to somebody who you thought was not telling you the full story behind a situation, probably negative, that took place in the past.

Comment: Thank you. I described the problem more, however your answer was useful.